# symfony No route found for "GET

Tags: symfony

I changed the name of my controller and the routes in the controller and the templates that correspond to it. I even executed the bin/console debug:route to check routes [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3eZr.png)
but when I type http:/localhost:8000/admin/programation/circuit I get an error : No route found for "GET /admin/programation/circuit".
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwIGn.png)

Remark: everything was working perfectly before I change the controller name and the routes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zcaE.png)

Comment: You should show us some screenshots and some code. It's very difficult so find a problem without enough informations.

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots but they appear in a sort of link , You have to click on it to view the images.

Comment: Just for info, there is a "code" button you can use to enter code in your question.  All it does is indent the code four spaces.  Few people enjoy clicking on random, difficult to read, links.

Comment: Could you @Nada Touil please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your route is not correct. To you try to call the route

```
/admin/programation/circuit
```

But your route is

```
/admin/programation/circuit/
```

So i think that is the problem in your case. So you have to add the `/` or you should remove them from your action.

Comment: I left everything as it is,  I changed nothing and the day next everything was working well. I think all I had to do was to update my project

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that with the symfony routing system we could not declare a route with a path that ends with **'/'** only if the path of the rotue is outright the **'/'** (not préfixed with any thing).

In our case, the **index()** function is pointed to a route prefixed by *'/admin/programation/circuit'* and ended with *'/'* otherwise the following route becomes *'/admin/programation/circuit/'* and as you can see, it does not respect the **convention**.

What I tell you, is to redefine the configuration in this way, so that the path becomes empty for the `index()` function. 
 To define you route in a proper way, you can prefix even the name of the route [(from version 3.4)](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-prefix-all-controller-route-names)

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/programation/circuit", name="admin_programtion_circuit_")
 */
 class BackofficeProgramationController {

  /**
   * @Route("", name="index")
   */
    public function index() {...}
 }
```